# Selection of Logo

Tags: discussion, electropus, community-decision

Okay, I'm gonna bring it up...

**This community should select a logo**, its part of the [essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

So **I propose we put ideas/examples for logos here, and vote for the one we want**.

Comment: http://www.google.com/images?q=chiphacker+logo still has some of the old proposals in the cache from the original logo question, which should maybe be resurrected here?  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671/help-us-choose-the-new-chiphacker-com-logo

Answer (score 17):

Ok this community already had a logo. The Electropus, may be some robotics element should be added to it.

[image]

Edit: Here he is without the text, in high-res glory:

[image: no text]

Comment: my vote is for electropus

Comment: He's cute, but don't be afraid to propose other alternatives.

Comment: I think we should remove the chiphacker text.  I'd do it myself, but my gimp-ery skills aren't super great.

Comment: gets my vote\0\0

Comment: I would like to think about how to add some robotics component to it as we are now Electronics & Robotics (as much as I don't like it)

Comment: laser-firing bionic arm?

Comment: robotics is still electronics in my mind. If you think this really needs to be added I understand, but I think putting E&R underneath(short form or typed out) would be a good addition.

Comment: @endolith - He's not a shark.

Comment: @Kortuk, robotics is quite more than electronics (one of the many reasons I didn't like the single robotics and electronics community concept). You have mechanical components, you have computer science components and some other components which do not have a clear domain space.

Comment: Controls, which is a boundary problem between mechanical, electrical and chemical fall into it. This community seems to be more geared towards the electrical approach to solving the problems, not saying I would ever turn away a good question. you have a lot of computer science, but with a heavy hardware aspect, in many places the domain of a computer engineer. Not saying these are set in stone, especially not the CS part, just saying, they fall in the domain of electronics in my mind. I understand your point though.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
       Electropus as a robot?
```

Comment: I don't see any lasers

Comment: Well - your not supposed to shine them in people's eyes! I'm sure he's got one, it's probably just turned off :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the alternative Electropus from [the original logo question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671/help-us-choose-the-new-chiphacker-com-logo)

[image]

Comment: Too nasty for me

Comment: He was always my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the old [Electronics Exchange](http://www.stackexchangesites.com/electronics-exchange/) logo, in case anyone likes that.  I can't find a bigger version:

[image]